# Any good .net packet sniffers around?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am looking for one to use from my c# application. Anyone knows a free one?

Comment: Why do you want one written in .NET? Why not use Fiddler or Microsoft Network Monitor, both of which are free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [SharpPcap](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx), which is a .NET-Wrapper for [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

Comment: That seems what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[A Network Sniffer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx)

[Packet Sniffer in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fyratkocak/PacketSniffer12032005034955AM/PacketSniffer.aspx)