# .net packet sniffing: attempt to create socket causes access error

Tags: .net, sockets

I'm working with the code from [Any good .net packet sniffers around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271001/any-good-net-packet-sniffers-around)

Within the project and in a stand-alone, I try to create a socket using the following line:

```
mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
```

On that line, I immediately get an exception

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket 
in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

I don't think this is a problem with the account permissions. I can run Fiddler under this account just fine.

Is this the correct way to open a listener for outgoing packets? If so, what do I need to do to avoid the permission error?

**Update**: .net 4.0 Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: If I run the code in Linqpad I get the same error.  But if I launch Linqpad as "Run as adminstrator", I can execute the code without any problem.  Not sure how Fiddler is doing it, but it does seem to be some permission related issue.

Comment: Does it work if you use SocketType.Stream instead of Raw?

Comment: I suspect that in current versions of Windows, the user must have Administrator privileges to get raw sockets. There's a long history on that topic, some of which you can see here: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2001/06/25/steve_gibson_really_is_off/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create raw sockets without administrative privileges.

> Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm not sure what Fiddler is, but it might be using UAC to automatically get admin privs.

Also, if you're looking for a decent .net packet sniffer, you might want to check out [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/), which wraps the already awesome libpcap.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a Web Debugging Proxy. Very handy for testing web services, among other things.