# Creating an effective packet sniffer in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, packet

I'm looking to create what I call a proxy, although that definition is probably somewhat inaccurate.

Typically, you have something like this:

```
Client --------- Server
```

What I want to do is introduce a proxy, without a new layer, like this:

```
Client ----+---- Server
           |
         Proxy
```

I do not want this:

```
Client---Proxy---Server
```

I understand that WinPCap does something similar to this, but it's an under documented subject as far as I can see.

So far I've tried a few things, most notably listening on the same port as the client for messages. This resulted in little more than receiving a load of crap packets from random applications (in spite of listening on a specific port). I couldn't find a lot to suggest I was reading the correct data, although I believe I have found that now, after making some minor modifications.

Does anyone know of any reason against using this method? Or is there some more sustainable way of doing it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the intercepted messages? If it's just for diagnostics, try .NET Tracing.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I intend to use them as part of an end-user application, to gather data about what's happening on a game server.

Comment: In that case I wonder if the game server has an API or some plugin system that lets you gather the data you want, as the game network traffic most likely is encrypted, obfuscated or otherwise relatively hard to process. I understand you cannot alter the server or client, so without direct communication with the server you'll _have_ to resort to listening to and understanding the network traffic. You can use WinPCap for that, but apart from the possible difficulty reading the data, its format may change between server versions, requiring you to alter your program.

Comment: @CodeCaster The data is XTEA encrypted and I'm fully aware of how I can decipher it using a key which is stored in the memory of the game client. I could potentially alter the client to redirect all data through my application, but if possible it would be much nicer to avoid having to reroute.

Comment: @XtrmJosh Are you familiar with Wireshark? When I've had similar sorts of problems I've used Wireshark to grab the actual capture and then just analyzed it in .NET (tshark/tcpdump may be appropriate here too). Alternatively Wireshark has very nice packet filter extensibility support so you can write code (but not .NET) without too much trouble to split apart your packets. I know that's not spot on for what you're asking, but hope it helps.

Comment: Wireshark uses WinPCap as it's network interface, although it use a very useful piece of software, it is miles off from what I need at the minute. I need something I can embed into a .NET application, preferably which I've written myself to make maintaining it easier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want what is called Raw Socket access (and use a hub or a switch that can send all the packets to your network adapter). You also want your network card in what is called "promiscuous mode", where it takes in all packets without filtering on MAC-address.

When you both get the traffic on the wire and your network adapter takes them in unfiltered, your program will get all the packets exactly as they are sent on the network (although you have to make sure you OS's TCP-UDP/IP stack doesn't sneak in an pick up TCP packets you would want to listen to, but if you target two other computers configuration that would not be a problem.

I'm not sure how well windows does this, but anyway.

When you get the packets, you have to read the ethernet headers (and you can filter based on the targets mac addresses), and then you have to pick out the IP-packets, as well as the TCP/UDP-packets and put them in order to get something reasonable out of the traffic. Not super-easy, but far from impossible either.

Answer (score 5):

If you look for packet sniffer instead of proxy it'll give you more relevant links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C
- [Any good .net packet sniffers around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271001/any-good-net-packet-sniffers-around)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fyratkocak/PacketSniffer12032005034955AM/PacketSniffer.aspx

[EDIT - something else to check is whether promiscuous mode is enabled on the network card. This tells the network card to pass all the packets up the stack, regardless of content. Without this, you might not get all the packets that you'd expect. More about this [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) and [how to enable promiscuous mode on Windows 7+](http://windows7themes.net/enable-promiscuous-mode-manually-in-windows-7.html)]

Comment: The first link you posted there is almost what I'm looking for, but in order to make use of it I'd need to spend a long time analysing the code provided. I may have been slightly optimistic in hoping that somebody might know the answer themselves, and be able to provide it... Not sure.