# TcpListerner does not catch traffic on port 1433

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener

I am trying to catch SQL Management Studio TCP network communication. As you probably know, it is happening (also) over port 1433.
Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1433);
     listener.Start();
     listener.AcceptTcpClient();

     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Problem here is that I never get over `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` line. For me it seems that TcpListener did not catch the packet at all.
When running this I have simultaneously opened Wireshark. There I can clearly see e.g.:

> Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 2481, Dst Port: 1433, Seq: 0,
>   Len: 0

It means that there is traffic on the network, but TcpListener is not catching it.

Any suggestion what am I missing - doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping this within a `try-catch` block and checking for possible exception messages? It could be blowing up when you start the listener and this could give you a bit more information about the issue.

Comment: Is SQL itself already up and listening on port 1433 on the same machine?

Comment: @RionWilliams: Just tried and nothing happens -> no exception. Anyway I'm running it in Visual Studio so pretty sure that debugger would signal me any exception that happened.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: No, I stopped all SQL services locally. I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL DB (if that matters).

Comment: Shortly You open telnet client in your computer And Run this code in CMD

pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an effective packet sniffer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768137/creating-an-effective-packet-sniffer-in-net)

Answer (score -1):

I solve this issue ,

I write this code in c# and after  i am  waiting  debug status.
After I open [windows features telnet client](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.windows-7-enabling-telnet-client.aspx)
then c# code step to  `listener.AcceptTcpClient();`
then The code Run

Shortly You open  telnet client in your computer 
And Run this code in CMD

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question asked?

Comment: I understand you got a related problem, but the original question makes no mention of anything to do with telnet, so explaining how to install the telnet client on Windows doesn't help OP or anybody else visiting this question. a) This is not an answer to the question (I have flagged it as such). b) If you want to provide this information, you should do so as a comment. I see you have done that, but as it stands, the comment you did post isn't clear on how you feel this relates.

Comment: Please read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to answer questions on StackOverflow. Pay particular attention to `Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.`